# node js xhr polling too much time 25 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, socket.io

[image]I am building an application in this application i add new item for different events from Admin Panel and object just populated by node js socket on frontend and i am getting in few polling request getting two much time.

`:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6EC8Z7&sid=gKbo2MATsLn2BqtpAAAg`

setting i used:-
`var io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log('user disconnected');
});


  socket.on('JoinEventOneRoom', function(data) {
    var id = data.id;
    var room = 'notify_event_one_list_'+id;
    console.log('Add event one Room Joined sucessfully', room);
    socket.join(room);
  });

  socket.on('JoinEventTwoRoom', function(data) {
    var id = data.id;
    var room = 'notify_event_two_'+id;
    console.log('Delete Event Two Joined sucessfully', room);
    socket.join(room);
  });
});
```

**React js code**

```
const socket = SocketIOClient(WSC.nodeBaseURL, { transports: ['polling'] });
socket.connect()
```

Need help what i am missing here.
I am using 2.3.0 version for both socket.io and socket.io-client